# How to return string count in multiple files in Linux

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, count

I have multiple xml files and I want to count some string in it.
How to return string count with files names in Linux?
The string I want to count InvoıceNo:
Result will be;

```
       test.xml InvoiceCount:2
       test1.xml InvoiceCount:5
       test2.xml InvoiceCount:10
```

Comment: How does ` test.xml` correspond to `InvoiceCount` as 2? Where do we map?

Comment: invoicecount writes in every xml in same way.

Comment: @1010111100011, please always do add sample Input for our easiness in code tags, it will be good for us to understand the question more clearly. Thank you and keep sharing, keep learning, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the following code

```
PATTERN=InvoiceNo

for file in *.xml
do
   count=$(grep -o $PATTERN "$file" | wc -l)
   echo "$file" InvoiceCount:$count
done
```

Output

```
test.xml InvoiceCount:1
test1.xml InvoiceCount:2
test2.xml InvoiceCount:3
```

Refered from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may help you in same, since you haven't shown any sample Inputs so not tested it.

```
awk 'FNR==1{if(count){print value,"InvoiceCount:",count;count=""};value=FILENAME;close(value)} /InvoiceCount/{count++}' *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -c` to get the count of matching lines

```
for file in *.xml ; do
   count=$(grep -c $PATTERN $file)
   if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
     echo "$file $PATTERN: $count"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First the test files:

```
$ cat foo.xml
InvoiceCount InvoiceCount
InvoiceCount
$ cat bar.xml
InvoiceCount
```

The GNU awk using `gsub` for counting:

```
$ awk '{
    c+=gsub(/InvoiceCount/,"InvoiceCount")
} 
ENDFILE {
    print FILENAME, "InvoiceCount: " c
    c=0
}' foo.xml bar.xml
foo.xml InvoiceCount: 3
bar.xml InvoiceCount: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A little shell skript will do want you want

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *
do
  awk '{count+=gsub(" InvoıceNo","")}
       END {print FILENAME, "InvoiceCount:" count}' $file

done
```

Put the code in a file (e.g. counter.sh) and run it like this:

counter.sh text.xml text1.xml text2.xml